# Extract Value (duplicated) in R

Tags: r, string

I have a data frame of value

```
df <- data.frame(value =c('[2000,2000]','[2200,2200]','[2010,2010]'))
```

and I just want to have a column with

```
newdf <- data.frame(newvalue = c(2000, 2200, 2010))
```

how to do that in r

Answer (score 2):

Using `str_extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>% 
   mutate(newvalue = as.numeric(str_extract(value, "\\d+")))
```

-output

```
df
       value newvalue
1 [2000,2000]     2000
2 [2200,2200]     2200
3 [2010,2010]     2010
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is more elegant, but if you cant access external packages, in base R you could try:

```
gsub("\\[.+\\,|\\]", "", df$value)

df$newvalue <- gsub("\\[.+,|\\]", "", df$value)

#         value newvalue
# 1 [2000,2000]     2000
# 2 [2200,2200]     2200
# 3 [2010,2010]     2010
```

Or via the comment by @onyambu

```
stack(mapply(jsonlite::fromJSON, df$value)[1,])

#   values         ind
# 1   2000 [2000,2000]
# 2   2200 [2200,2200]
# 3   2010 [2010,2010]
```

Answer (score 1):

It could also be a great usecase of `substr`:

```r
df[, "newvalue"] <- 
  substr(df$value, 2, 5) |> as.numeric()
```

Output:

```
        value newvalue
1 [2000,2000]     2000
2 [2200,2200]     2200
3 [2010,2010]     2010
```